# Debugging a function

Tags: c, cs50

In this C code, I am trying to extract out the information of the user. There are 2 parts to this code: one is getting the account value right and another is printing out the user information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int acc();
```

In this part the information is stored, and have to extract the information with i; after getting the i value from the second part, the code will then print out the user information.

```
int main()
{   
    int i ;
    acc();
    int acc[6] = {12341 ,12342 ,12342 ,12344,12345 };
    string name[6] = {"aabb" , "ccdd" ,"eeff","gghh","iijj"};
    string password[6] = {"a1b2c3" , "a2b2c3" ,"A3b2c3" , "A4b2c3" , "A5b2c3" };
    int initial[6] =  {5000 , 1000 , 25000 , 700 , 100000};

    printf("info = %d,%s,%s,%d\n" , acc[i] ,name[i] , password[i] , initial[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

In this part, the code is trying to get the user input, acc number, and if the account is correct, the i value would be set.

```
int acc()
{
    // finding the account and the other information 
    int acc , i ; 

    printf("Account number: ");
    scanf("%d\n" , &acc);

    if (acc == 12341)
    { 
        i = 0 ;
    }
    else if (acc == 12342)
    {
        i = 1; 
    }
    else if (acc == 12343)
    {
        i = 2;
    }
    else if (acc == 12344)
    {
        i = 3;
        printf("lose\n");
    }
    else if (acc == 12345)
    {
        i = 4;
    }
    return i;
};
```

For your info, every time I print out the code, the terminal would always give me the same value which is:

```
info = 12341 ,"aabb" , "a1b2c3" , 5000 .
```

Comment: `int acc()` or `int acc[6]` or `int acc`? Very confusing, not only for other readers but probably for yourself as well.

Comment: Also if the input is neither of the checked values, what does the `acc` *function* return then?

Comment: is it necessary to name absolutely everything `acc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
    acc();
```

you are throwing away what is returned from the function `acc()` and leaving the variable `i` uninitialized.
Values of uninitialized non-static local variables are indeterminate and using them invokes *undefined behavior*.

Instead of the line, you will have to assign what is returned from the function `acc()` to the variable `i` like this:

```
    i = acc();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , however there is an error , extension.c:16:12: error : called object type 'int[6]' is not a function pointer , i = acc(i);  May i know what does this mean please , thank you .

Comment: You are using the same name for the function and an array, so it is causing trouble. It seems the function should be called like `select_acc`.